# Do I need a Windows 7 SP1 key to use an SP1 installer?

Tags: windows-7, license-key, installation-media

I'm performing a fresh install of Windows 7 Pro on a machine with an associated product key, but there's no longer a windows partition (can't create a recovery cd) and I don't have the installation media.

I found out that you can get the installer through a Microsoft cdn (DigitalRiver http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links), but this is an SP1 installer (x64) (I have 10 hours to wait until the download finishes). The sticker with the product key reads:

> Windows 7 Pro OA

I've got Windows 7 Home Primium installed now, but I need the key for another machine, so I can`t activate it.

I`ve already tried:

- using the OEM key during setup
- using Anytime Update with the OEM key (after running 1 round of windows updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Anytime Upgrade worked after all, when I returned the next morning, the PC had rebooted to Pro. Activating with the attached key worked as well.